# megacli unconfigured(bad) disk status

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid, megacli

megacli tell me, there is an issue with one of my disk.
Howerver, I am not sure that this disk actually exist.

Here is megaclisas-status info :

```
-- Controller information --
-- ID | H/W Model           | RAM    | Temp | BBU    | Firmware     
c0    | PERC 6/i Integrated | 256MB  | N/A  | Good   | FW: 6.3.3.0002 

-- Array information --
-- ID | Type   |    Size |  Strpsz | Flags | DskCache |   Status |  OS Path | CacheCade |InProgress   
c0u0  | RAID-5 |    136G |   64 KB | RA,WB |  Default |  Optimal | /dev/sda | None      |None         

-- Disk information --
-- ID  | Type | Drive Model                           | Size     | Status          | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI Device ID
c0u0p0 | HDD  | MAXTOR ATLAS10K5_073SASBP00J2106XAK A | 67. Gb   | Online, Spun Up | Unknown  | 39C  | [32:0]   | 0       
c0u0p1 | HDD  | MAXTOR ATLAS10K5_073SASBP00J20ZCKZK A | 67. Gb   | Online, Spun Up | Unknown  | 37C  | [32:3]   | 3       
c0u0p2 | HDD  | MAXTOR ATLAS10K5_073SASBP00J2105D5K A | 67. Gb   | Online, Spun Up | Unknown  | 36C  | [32:2]   | 2       

-- Unconfigured Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                           | Size     | Status              | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI Device ID
c0uXpY  | HDD  | MAXTOR ATLAS10K5_073SASBP00J210608K A | 0 KB     | Unconfigured(bad)   | Unknown  | N/A  | [32:1]   | Unknown
```

And here is what `megacli -PDInfo -PhysDrv [32:1] -a0` returns :

```
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 1
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 1
WWN: 
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 7.999 ZB [0xfffffffffff00000 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
Device Firmware Level: BP00
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x50010b9000241c0e
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data: MAXTOR  ATLAS10K5_073SASBP00J210608K        A   
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: Unknown 
Link Speed: Unknown 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unconfigured Bad usually means an improperly removed device that has been reconnected? Do you recall anything like that? You can mark it as good but it might start a rebuild so check your RAID status before proceeding to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I checked physically the server.

It seems a disk in the raid completely crash and a hot spare disk has done it's job to replace the crashed disk.

So I was confused because megaclisas-status don't display global spare.